# Re-requesting permissions to google drive for a project fails

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I started a project requesting the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly`. However, I have noticed that the scope was not enough for the operation of reading from a file. So i changed the scope to `drive.readonly`, however no permission screen was shown. Then I thought I would revoke the permissions in my google drive, afterwards, however, nothing worked. Then I decided to start a new project, set up the request for a `drive.file` scope and I also generated new credentials (in json format). Unfortunately, I keep on getting:

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Token has been expired or revoked."
}
```

and no permission screen is being displayed when I start the application...
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting Saved credentials from my spring boot project seems to have worked. Then, during the execution of the programme I got the web link for approving authentication request again.